# Dynamically styling element in react component using state

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Hi I am trying to add a matrix3d value to the h1 which will update on scroll and move the h1, however it doesn't seem to have any effect a but I can see in the console log that the values are indeed changing when I log this.state.transform, can anyone advice me on where I'm going wrong please

```
import styles from "./marquee.module.scss";

class Marquee extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.renderMatrix, { passive: true });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.renderMatrix);
  }

  renderMatrix = () => {
    const distanceFromTop = window.pageYOffset;
    this.setState({
      transform: `matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, ${distanceFromTop}, 0, 0, 1)`,
    });
    console.log(this.state.transform)
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className={styles.marquee} style={{ transform: this.state.transform }}>
          DESIGNER UI DESIGNER UI DESIGNER
        </h1>
        <h2>DESIGNER UI DESIGNER UI DESIGNER</h2>
        <h2>DESIGNER UI DESIGNER UI DESIGNER</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Marquee;
```

Comment: if you inspect the element in your browser, can you see the updated state ?, if not can you provide us with your CSS code.

Comment: style={{ transform: this.state.transform }} isn't applying because it is saying transform is null, this inline style is the only css

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

`this.state.transform` is initially undefined, so `style={{ transform: this.state.transform }}` fails.

## Solution

Define initial state

```
state = {
  transform: `matrix3d(
    1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1)`,
}
```

[image: Edit matrix3d scrolling marquee]